# How to disable counting child rows without using the pager plugin

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I have a table where I've made some child rows and given them the hidden css class. I display the filtered and total row counts elsewhere in my html and upon first loading the correct numbers are displayed. However, when I turn off all the filters the child rows get included in the filtered and total row counts.

Here is a jsfiddle demoing the problem (I've included all the code as there's a lot going on and I want to check if anything is clashing): https://jsfiddle.net/Simon_b/xo8d5buz/7/

There are two rows, each with a child row which are hidden. Upon loading you can see that "Variants passing filters" reads "2 / 2"; this is correct. The 10th column (ExAC/gnomAD MAF) has a default filter value. If you click the dropdown and remove the default value then "Variants passing filters" will read "4 / 4" therefore including the childrows in the counts. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Turning on the debug option doesn't show any errors in the console.

I've tried being explicit that filter_childRows is set to false, but that isn't helping. I'm not too familiar with javascript and jquery beyond very simple stuff.

```
filter_childRows: false
```